# numpy memory erros on all possible combinations

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, out-of-memory

I have been using `_list = np.unique(np.stack(np.meshgrid(*_load), -1).reshape(-1, len(_load)), axis=0)` to generate a list of all possible combinations, which worked fine on list of list that look like,

> [[1, 2, 3], [8, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

Howeveer, if I want to find all possibles on something like

> [[3, 4, 69, 134, 39, 42, 46, 15, 99, 20, 120, 123, 93], [130, 5, 7, 139, 14, 143, 33, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 58, 60, 62, 67, 84, 85, 87, 91, 105, 106, 107, 111, 121, 127], [130, 5, 7, 139, 14, 143, 33, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 58, 60, 62, 67, 84, 85, 87, 91, 105, 106, 107, 111, 121, 127], [1, 132, 133, 135, 138, 11, 12, 142, 16, 147, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 35, 36, 40, 47, 54, 57, 63, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 140, 76, 81, 83, 88, 90, 92, 144, 98, 100, 103, 109, 110, 112, 114, 118, 122], [1, 132, 133, 135, 138, 11, 12, 142, 16, 147, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 35, 36, 40, 47, 54, 57, 63, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 140, 76, 81, 83, 88, 90, 92, 144, 98, 100, 103, 109, 110, 112, 114, 118, 122], [128, 129, 2, 131, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 141, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 137, 56, 59, 61, 64, 65, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 86, 89, 94, 95, 96, 97, 101, 102, 145, 104, 108, 146, 113, 115, 116, 117, 119, 136, 124, 125, 126], [128, 129, 2, 131, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 141, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 137, 56, 59, 61, 64, 65, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 86, 89, 94, 95, 96, 97, 101, 102, 145, 104, 108, 146, 113, 115, 116, 117, 119, 136, 124, 125, 126], [128, 129, 2, 131, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 141, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 137, 56, 59, 61, 64, 65, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 86, 89, 94, 95, 96, 97, 101, 102, 145, 104, 108, 146, 113, 115, 116, 117, 119, 136, 124, 125, 126], [128, 129, 2, 131, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 141, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 32, 34, 37, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 137, 56, 59, 61, 64, 65, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 86, 89, 94, 95, 96, 97, 101, 102, 145, 104, 108, 146, 113, 115, 116, 117, 119, 136, 124, 125, 126]]

I get a `MemoryError` in python, obviously I need to change my approach, any ideas? I was thinking I would need to end up writing the intermittent events to file, but I don't know how to get these built ins to do that.

Comment: Notmally, one would use an iterator for this (see `itertools`). I don't see e benefit from using NumPy here. NumPy array are great for some purposes but not for others.

Comment: Your result shape would be `(comb, len(_load))`, where comb is: 
`comb = 1 \n
for l in _load: \n
    comb *= len(l)`
which for your example is: 2221241971137696, thus, exceeding any available RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, but your result is unrepresentable.

Note in particular that your `np.unique` is useless, because each `load[i]` contains no duplicates, so the size of the result is the product of the lengths of the lists times the number of lists

```
>>> np.prod([len(i) for i in second_example], dtype=np.int64) * 9
2498897217529908
```

Assuming optimistically that each integer is a `uint8`, that's 2.2 PiB (Pebibytes), which far exceeds current RAM configurations.

Even if you don't try to put the whole result in memory at once, even iterating over this is going to take a long time - assuming a generous 4GHz processor and a single clock cycle per result, you're looking at longer than a week to finish

Comment: Ok thank you, I was afraid of this.I'll try to come up with another way path to solve this problem.